# Rails 'multiple inheritance' model- ActiveRecord object with a property which is another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, activerecord, model, activemerchant

I'm probably asking for the wrong thing. What I'd like is a model which extends the class [ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Location](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/location.rb), but is also saved in the database and has other neat active record associations like multiple employees, working day schedules, etc.

I know I can't inherit from multiple classes- what's the best way to create a Location class with both ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Location properties & methods and additional ActiveRecord properties & associations?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Location and include ActiveModel::Model and/or other ActiveRecord modules you desire.

Comment: So it would be: class WarehouseLocation /
  extend ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Location / 
  include ActiveRecord::Base ?